# jQuery overlay click event trigger navigation click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, slideshow, history.js

I've got an overlay set over an image that I'd like to act as previous and next controls. The code below worked fine until I implemented the History.js plugin.. now things are a little funky and I'm not sure why. Chrome's console shows no errors, but the image isn't toggling appropriately.

Thanks for your help.

Test site: http://brantley.dhut.ch/

JavaScript:

```
$("#ol").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('a.prev').click();
});
$("#or").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('a.next').click();
});
```

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 14, assuming the desired behavior is what I expect.

Comment: I figured it out.. well, not really, 'cause I dont understand it, but I fixed it. Instead of creating a click event for the previous and next buttons, I went into the plug ins library and triggered the direct events. So weird that it didn't work this way though... It should have.

Answer (score 0):

Could try this:

```
$("#ol").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('a.prev').click();
      return false; //added
});
$("#or").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('a.next').click();
      return false; //added
});
```

Also, check in Firefox with Firebug console if you get any Javascript errors on page load, might be something not related causing your code to not work correctly

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is one of the actions return false; encompasses.. and I checked in Chrome's dev console. Thanks for the answer though! :)